# Kendo UI and responsive design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, responsive-design

Is Kendo UI suitable for responsive design for mobile devices? Or I should use bootstrap etc... for responsive mobile design?

Answer (score 11):

Well, these are different beasts.

[**Twitter Bootstrap**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) (it was just a typo in the question, right?) is, first of all, a CSS framework. Which, among other things, lets you easily create different layouts/stylesets for different types of devices and switch between them (utilizing media-queries).

[**Kendo UI**](http://www.kendoui.com/), however, is first of all a JavaScript framework, and its main purpose is simplifying development of web applications. In other words, it concentrates mostly on *behavior* side of web development.

It's certainly possible to use Kendo UI Mobile (a part of Kendo UI family) for 'universalizing' your web applications - look at this [helpful tutorial](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/12-09-11/universal_mobile_apps_with_html5_and_kendo_ui) for introduction of some techniques. However, it's said in the same tutorial:

> What about responsive design, you ask?
>
> Responsive design is great for creating mobile sites, but it’s not as
>   useful for creating mobile apps. Responsive design can help you hide,
>   show, resize, and reformat UI for screens of varying size, but it is
>   less suited for presenting completely different modes of usability on
>   different form factors (such as phones and tablets).

Comment: thanks, Twiter Bootstrap is right decision for responsive design for mobile phones ?

Comment: I think so. Yet you may find [this article](http://designshack.net/articles/css/which-is-right-for-me-22-responsive-css-frameworks-and-boilerplates-explained/) comparing several CSS frameworks (ready for responsive design) helpful for choosing the solution for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI and Twitter Bootstrap are not mutually exclusive! Grouping them is a category mistake; they are each solutions to two distinct problems. See this demo from Telerik on [Kendo + Bootstrap](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bootstrap/)

**Kendo UI** is a *UI development* framework.

**Twitter Bootstrap** is a responsive page layout framework.

Both Kendo *and* Bootstrap ship with colors and styles set to defaults, but the source LESS files can be customized for both.

*Further*, Kendo UI includes widgets that are designed for a mobile experience, and many widgets have configuration that make them suitable for a mobile experience.